# Select box validation using ngModel in Angular2

Tags: angular2-template

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
     <div class="ui-input-group">
          <select #categoryVal="ngModel" class="form-control" name="staffCategory" [(ngModel)]="staffCategory">
               <option value=null >--Select--</option>
               <option *ngFor="let cat of applicationCategories" value="{{cat.categoryCode}}">{{cat.categoryName}}</option>
           </select>
           <span class="input-bar"></span>
           <label class="control-label">Category<span style="color:#f44336;">*</span></label>
     </div>
     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm  ripple" [disabled]="categoryVal.errors"  name="searchPerson" (click)="searchNewPerson($event)">Search</button>
</div>
```

Here if value of select box is  `<option value=null >--Select--</option>`  then need to disable the search and give a tool tip(default form authentication 'Pleas fill the fields') by highlighting that field.
THe above code is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Button Disabling
 Set value to to empty when --Select--

`<option value="">--Select--</option>`

and in your button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm  ripple" [disabled]="categoryVal==''"  name="searchPerson" (click)="searchNewPerson($event)">Search</button>
```